# Why won't the JPanel change color and stay that way?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm working on a assignment for school but I got a problem :P.
I got this code:

```
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    MyPanel b = (MyPanel)e.getSource();
    System.out.println("ID: "+b.getId()+"");
    b.setColor(Color.blue);
}
```

In the MyPanel object I got:

```
public void setColor(Color kleur) {
    if(this.getBackground()==Color.white) {
        this.setBackground(kleur);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

When I enter the panel with my mouse the color flashes that I entered. But I want it to stay the color so I can draw a trail in a Jform with 500 Jpanels(I've added them to a ArrayList but this part works just fine)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the whole `MouseListener` code? Also, are you sure that the background is set to white before? You could try that out by removing the if statement in your `MyPanel#setColor()` method.

Comment: I believe you should be re-coloring the JPanel in the paint() method. And your mouse listener should change a variable that gets used in there.

Comment: It's unnecessary to re-color the JPanel in the paint() method.  Setting the background of the JPanel works fine.  There is no need to write a custom paint() method unless you absolutely need it.

Comment: @ErickRobertson Good point, maybe he wrote his own `paintComponents()` that draws something hiding the background. That would also explain the "flashing" he describes. -> @Bram, could you also tell us if you have overwritten the `paintComponents()` method in your MyPanel and if yes, we would need that code too.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Here is my paintComponents:
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25,25));
            if(colorr=="zwart"){
            setKleur(Color.black);
            Border lineBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
            this.setBorder(lineBorder);
            }
}

Comment: @Bram `if (colorr=="zwart") {` -> you **can't** compare `String`s that way. You should use the `String#equals(String)` method instead: `if (colorr.equals("zwart")) {` instead.

Comment: You should read about how to use `paintComponent`.  It's a red flag to me that you're calling `setKleur` from within this method.  `paintComponent` should only be painting what is necessary.  It should not be setting the color at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @ErickRobertson's comment on the question, I guess the problem is the following:

Your `MyPanel` replaces the `JPanel#paintComponents()` method. Is that possible? If so, you could do the following. In your `MyPanel#setColor(Color)` method, you don't set the background, but a field containing your new background color:

```
private Color backgroundColor = Color.white;
public void setColor(Color kleur) {
  backgroundColor = kleur;
  repaint();
}
```

Then, in your `MyPanel#paintComponents(Graphics)`:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  // draw background
  g.setColor(backgroundColor);
  g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
  // draw your stuff here
}
```

Comment: @Bram what are you already using? `paintComponents()`? That's exactly what I am saying. Your problem might be, that you use `paintComponents()` and draw something over your background. That's why you would need to realise the background color the way I am proposing.

Comment: I solved it the way you said I forgot to change the painComponent method so After I entered the block and I used repaint the object only knew the default color

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure that only one JPanel is visible at a time.**

When you add the JPanels to their parent, are they all going on top of each other?  If so, then when you call `repaint()` on one of them, it's being repainted immediately and you can see it as blue.  But as soon as the whole window repaints again, the JPanels are painted in the order they have been added and the last one is ultimately painted on top.  This panel still has a white background, so that's what you're seeing.

Make sure only one of these panels are visible at a time, or that you have some plan in place to manage these panels so that only one of them are visible.  Otherwise, make sure they are laid out in a grid or some other way so they don't appear on top of each other.

Comment: I place all the JPanels in a GridLayout

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `MouseListener` implemented, since you are getting the panel from the `MouseEvent`. It's easier to have the panels implement the `MouseListener` and let them decide when to change color for themselves.

```
class Panel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    public Panel() {
        // Make sure the listener listens 
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        setColor(Color.blue);
    }
    // ... other mouselisteners can be ignored or implemented as needed
}
```

You can still keep a reference to some other class if you need it to be notified of a mouseenter. Just create a private member and set the reference in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setColor(Color kleur) {
    if(this.getBackground()==Color.white) {
        this.setBackground(kleur);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

dont use == repalce with equals and try invalidate(. Your code is basically saying only replace background if background is white ???